# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'" when calling `to_mongo` in MongoEngine

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

I have the following Python code to connect to a [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) (2.0.1 installed through MacPorts) database using [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/) (0.7.9 installed through pip):

```
import datetime
from mongoengine import *

connect('mydb')

class Post(EmbeddedDocument):
    title = StringField(required=True)
    description = StringField(required=True)
    author = StringField(required=True)
    pub_date = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.datetime.now)

p = Post()
p.author = "genba"
p.title = "Test post"
p.description = "This is a test post"
```

When calling the method `to_mongo` on the objet `p`, I get the following traceback:

```
env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base.pyc in to_mongo(self)
   1040         # Only add _cls and _types if allow_inheritance is not False
   1041         if not (hasattr(self, '_meta') and
-> 1042            self._meta.get('allow_inheritance', ALLOW_INHERITANCE) == False):
   1043             data['_cls'] = self._class_name
   1044             data['_types'] = self._superclasses.keys() + [self._class_name]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

As you may notice, the error is produced by a line of code in MongoEngine's code, installed in the virtual environment `env` with [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).

This error actually arises both when I embed the document `Post` into another document by using an [`EmbeddedDocumentField`](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField), and when I just paste the previous code into the Python interpreter (until now, I've just used [IPython](http://ipython.org/) instead of the vanilla Python interpreter).

I've tried debugging with `pdb` and searching the internet, but I haven't got to find any useful information on this issue. **The only thing I can tell is that `self._meta` is `None` and that causes the exception to be raised.** But why it is `None` or what that should mean… I don't know.

**Why do I get this error?** It's definitely in MongoEngine's code, but is it cause by MongoEngine or by my code/data? **How can I solve it?**

Thanks in advance.

PS: As additional information, I plan to use this with [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), but the previous code can be run apart from Django, and I've done my tests like that (without Django, just with IPython, like I mentioned before).

Comment: What version of MongoEngine are you running - all that is covered by automated tests, so I'm thinking it might be a version or setup issue.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. It's MongoEngine 0.7.9. I've just edited the question and added the version numbers.

Comment: `self._meta` must be `None`

Comment: Yes, `self._meta` is `None`, but why and what should that mean? I don't know. That is actually what is causing the exception to be raised, and what should be fixed. I cannot, however, just add a `try…catch` into MongoEngine's code or something like that, because I don't really know what that code is supposed to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Should I open a ticket at [MongoEngine's GitHub page](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine)?

Comment: I cant reproduce using your code on the 0.7.9 branch.  Lets just double check - can you print mongoengine.VERSION ?

Comment: Just chasing this up!

Comment: Sorry for the delay. As I mentioned, I'm using MongoEngine 0.7.9 (installed from pip into a virtualenv).
Printing mongoengine.VERSION thus produces the output: (0, 7, 9)